# extractvalue fails on using xpath with quotes

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting "ORA-21560: argument 3 is null, invalid, or out of range" error on running query:

```
SELECT extractvalue(xmltype(blob2clob(shblobdata.blobdata)),
    '/booked-order/ads/online-content[name="quantity"]/value')
FROM shblobdata
WHERE id=...;
```

the full error is:

```
ORA-21560: argument 3 is null, invalid, or out of range
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 978
ORA-06512: at "MORAS.BLOB2CLOB", line 14
```

> 21560 . 00000 -  "argument %s is null, invalid, or out of range"
>
> *Cause:    The argument is expecting a non-null, valid value but the
>              argument value passed in is null, invalid, or out of range.
>              Examples include when the LOB/FILE positional or size
>              argument has a value outside the range 1 through (4GB - 1),
>              or when an invalid open mode is used to open a file, etc.
>
> *Action:   Check your program and correct the caller of the routine
>              to not pass a null, invalid or out-of-range argument value.

I have tried to change "quantity" to ''quantity'' (changing single quote to two apostrophes), but got the same error.

The content of blob is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<booked-order>
    <ads>
        <online-content>
            <name>quantity</name>
            <value>19872</value>
        </online-content>
    </ads>
</booked-order>
```

Comment: Do you have the source for `MORAS.BLOB2CLOB`? Looks like a problem with how that is calling another function, rather than necessarily with the data in the BLOB; I don't think it's getting as far as `extractvalue()`, or even `xmltype()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your custom function MORAS.BLOB2CLOB.

Also the error message says clearly `ORA-06512: at "MORAS.BLOB2CLOB", line 14`

The extract itself is ok, when you keep out BLOB2CLOB and test with

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (xmltype ( (shblobdata.blobdata)), '/booked-order/ads/online-content[name="quantity"]/value')
  FROM (SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<booked-order>
    <ads>
        <online-content>
            <name>quantity</name>
            <value>19872</value>
        </online-content>
    </ads>
</booked-order>
' blobdata
          FROM DUAL) shblobdata
;
```

it returns `19872`

I'd first debug your function blob2clob with

```
SELECT blob2clob(shblobdata.blobdata)
  FROM shblobdata
 WHERE id=...;
```

And if that works ok continue on to the XML parts.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is clearly hurled by `BLOB2CLOB()`, which is not an Oracle built-in.  It's something you've written yourself or lifted from somewhere on the interwebs.  So there's not much we can do to help regarding it.

The more general point is, why are you storing XML in a BLOB?  The best apporach is to store it in a column defined as Oracle's XMLTYPE datatype.  Otherwise store it as a CLOB.